# How do I run a Ruby script remotely on Linux machine

Tags: ruby, linux, remote-server

I am connected to a Linux server from my Windows machine using putty. I need to create a ruby file and execute the same. Should I create the Ruby file on my machine or on Linux server? Please advise.

Comment: what do you mean by create?  write/compose?

Comment: yes to compose a ruby file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best workflow in this case would be to write the rb script in whatever environment you want ... many people like developing locally on their own machine (which has advantages), and many prefer developing it remotely on another machine.

Basically write it the same way as you would write any ruby file on your favorite text editor using your favorite method.

Then you upload the rile to the remote machine -- you can use software like **[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)** and then run the script using `ssh`:

```
$ ssh (server address)
$ ruby (path to wherever you put the script)
```

Comment: Uploading from Windows too often results in hapless newbie questions on SO about hard-to-diagnose (but in retrospect obvious) line ending problems. Please edit to emphasize the importance of using text mode in `ftp`, and/or use Unix line endings (LF only, not CR/LF) in your editor; then you can also use a better transfer method such as `scp`.

Comment: @tripleee totally missed that he was using windows :)  addressed the idea of line ending complications...i think...i don't really mix them often but I think that WinSCP deals with it for you.  thank you for your suggestions and let me know if there's anything else

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where you compose the script.

You can either compose it locally or remotely

When you're composing it localy you can do it with your well known GUI-Editor Tools like Notepad or so, but you'll have to upload the file to the server to use it there.

When you're composing it remotely you'll have to use CLI-Editors like nano or ViM for it, but you're able to run it instantly without uploading it

And you can run the script on the remote machine as usual

```
$ ruby path/to/you/script.rb
```

assuming ruby is already installed

Comment: If the connection is really flaky, local editing is more convenient. Otherwise, removing one step from the test-edit-upload-repeat cycle is a good way to improve productivity and reduce frustration. Some editors will allow you to transparently edit remote files, getting you the best of both worlds; personally, I can only recommend Emacs, although there must surely be (lesser!) native Windows text editors with this capability.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the ruby file on server you have to create it on the server.

Comment: I want to execute it from my windows machine

Comment: That's not what this means. If you log in with putty, what you do in there happens on the server, even though the user interface runs on your machine. But as others have noted, you can author the file on Windows and upload it to the server.